# ASP.NET [Add image to ISS - dll ?]

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm loading image from my database to temp file but my IIS can't see this file so I need to add it to my ISS somehow.
I saw some way here [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/desaijm/HTTPHandlersForImages11152005062705AM/HTTPHandlersForImages.aspx)
So question is how to make and work with ImageHandler.dll
Need I to create new dll application for it and then add to bin of my web app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [generic handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) for it. Here is a sample:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Deimand.Business;
using System.Configuration;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    { get{ return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["imageId"] != null)
        {
           byte[] imageContent = GetImageFromDataBase(context.Request.QueryString["imageId"]);
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageContent, 0, imageContent.Length);
        }
    }
}
```