# ASP.NET [Image Handler]

Tags: asp.net, image, httphandler, ashx

I'm still trying to load my image from database.
But that's not so easy with my skins to understand the shots :
[Using Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091819/asp-net-add-image-to-iss-dll)
I read this stuff and was on trying to make it but I found only one method :
Mapping some my page (in webconf) to this handler (ashx)

I need to use it in my page in my

and Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's pretty straight forward and has been answered before.

[Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)

where most novices get confused is that the image data is never assigned to any property of the asp.net image control.  instead the src of the image is assigned to the url of the image handler.  The image handler then writes the data to the response via Response.Write().

Comment: Also, check out [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net), it provides disk-cached blob serving and (optional) dynamic editing. [Disclaimer: I'm the author].