# How to display images in repeater from database

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell how to display images in repeater control from database (binary stream)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Use/learn [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Steps:

1. Develop an [image handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099545/asp-net-image-handler) and [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) it in web.config
2. Test it (handler) via `url`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a handler that returns the image something like this:

```
 System.IO.Stream responseStream =//stream from database
 MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
 CopyStream(responseStream, mem);
 byte[] buffer = mem.GetBuffer();
 context.Response.Clear();
 context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="image");
 context.Response.ContentType = "image/PNG";
 context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
 context.Response.End();
```

and then in your repeater i would call the handler something like this:

```
<img src="handlerName.ashx?id=<%# Eval("Id")%>" />
```