# Image cropped in rendering with GDI+

Tags: c#, image-processing, browser, gdi+

I am using my own class for image processing , like load , thumbnail , ....

In general ,  this code create images object;

```
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

and this code post it to `response` object to show in browser.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ContentType", "image/png");
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Result.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            memStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Result.Dispose();
```

In some cases , the browser(s) show the correct image but sometimes show the cropped image like this.

[image]

Is this image breaking related to my code or related to browsers ?

Answer (score 1):

If the image format is PNG, you need to use an intermediate MemoryStream (because PNGs require a seekable stream to be saved). Try using jpg file to see that your code is working.

Check [ASP.NET [Image Handler]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099545/asp-net-image-handler)