# read image from folder and database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

How can i read images from folder "images" and her name in the database using asp.net vb code
this is the code i use.

```
   Dim conn As SqlConnection
   Dim cmd As SqlCommand
   Dim cmdString As String = ("select TOP 20 * from tbl_news order by db_id desc ")
   conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\m7md\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AlAkhbar\AlAkhbar\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
   cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdString, conn)
   conn.Open()
   Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

   While (dr.Read)
       Response.Write("<div id=title>")
       Response.Write("<img src='images/db_img')  />")
       Response.Write("</div>")
       Response.Write("<div id=title>")
       Response.Write(dr("db_title"))
       Response.Write("<br/>")
       Response.Write("<br/>")
       Response.Write("</div>")
       Response.Write("<div id=sumury>")
       Response.Write(dr("db_sumury"))
       Response.Write("</div>")
       Response.Write("<div id=readmore>")
       Response.Write("<a href=readmore.aspx?id=" & dr("db_id").ToString & "> Readmore</a>")
       Response.Write("</div>")
       Response.Write("<hr/>")

   End While
```

Comment: "_ plz help me_" - we don't appreciate begging here. Also, you have many errors in your HTML. You can't have two elements with the same `id`, for instance. You should also read about using the Repeater or DataList controls.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an image handler. You can find more information here:

- [ASP.NET [Image Handler]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099545/asp-net-image-handler)
- [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database
- http://aspalliance.com/1322_Displaying_Images_in_ASPNET_Using_HttpHandlers.5

Comment: plz more details in coding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net 
The sample code is there. You can use @FlySwat sample code. I did not find fair copying over their answer here.